# Printing 2 statements on the same line

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I've successfully made a scraper that scrapes all 109 pages of the iPhone section on eBay.

The problem is that I need them to print on the same line. This is what it currently looks like[image: picture]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(colly.UserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0"))

    c.OnHTML(".s-item__title", func(element *colly.HTMLElement) {
        element.ChildAttr("heading", "role")
        fmt.Println(element.Text)
    })

    c.OnHTML(".s-item__price", func(element *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(element.Text)
    })

    c.Visit("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iPhone&_sacat=0&_pgn=1")
}
```

It's not even possible to navigate around this information. Can someone show me how I can get the Title along with the price on the same line?

I thought about renaming the element but it didn't work.

I would use printf or println, but then it just prints everything together.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I showed the output, I think that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using fmt.Print instead of fmt.Println

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
{
    fmt.Print("Title")
}
{
    fmt.Println("| Price")
}

{
    fmt.Print("Title")
}
{
    fmt.Println("| Price")
}
}
```

Comment: Then it prints everything on the same line, I want it to be like this:

Title | Price (new line)

Comment: You can use Println for 2nd print i.e for item price.

Comment: I tried that, but it still does not work, could you try?

Comment: That's not what I mean. Try running this code, it won't look like that. https://pastebin.com/yQYQ7VS6

Comment: Have a look at this. What might be happening is gocolly first scans the title tag in whole HTML and then is scans price tag. 
In this way you can store them and print accordingly
https://pastebin.com/q6jc1jNH

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251281/discussion-between-sahil-jangra-and-goggins).

Comment: after running the code it does not work as intended. https://pastebin.com/rYEjZ8Ug Only half of it works.

Comment: defer function prints the item along with price...
if you want single item also, you can log them in title block

Comment: do you know a better way to store the data (besides in an array?) Storing it in an array causes multiple problems.

Comment: It's a very difficult process. Will have to see wether any element has unique id for both item and price. Then it can be stored in a map.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `fmt.Println()` includes '`\n`' at the end. `ln` means new line. You can use `fmt.PrintF()` to format output however you want, it doesn't force a new line, if this is your issue.

Comment: Then it prints everything on the same line, I want it to be like this:

Title | Price (new line)

Comment: @goggins Don't use `.println()` on the name and use it on the price. This way, the name won't push the next printing thing on a new line, but the price will force one.